# Problem with memcached and php7, can't seem to be solved by current solutions

Tags: php, linux, memcached, alpine-linux, nextcloud

Hej!

So as you can read in the title, I have a problem with loading memcached on my server.
OS : Alpine Linux

I've seen that a lot of people have already had this issue but it's always on other OS, and the solutions can't seem to work for me.

There is the problem : I used the `php -v` command.

```
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php7/modules/memcached.so' (tried: /usr/lib/php7/modules/memcached.so (Error relocating /usr/lib/php7/modules/memcached.so: php_session_create_id: symbol not found), /usr/lib/php7/modules//usr/lib/php7/modules/memcached.so.so (Error loading shared library /usr/lib/php7/modules//usr/lib/php7/modules/memcached.so.so: No such file or directory)) in Unknown on line 0
PHP 7.3.17 (cli) (built: Apr 16 2020 23:18:12) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) 1997-2018 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.3.17, Copyright (c) 1998-2018 Zend Technologies
    with Zend OPcache v7.3.17, Copyright (c) 1999-2018, by Zend Technologies
```

Memcached is supposedly installed here : `/usr/lib/php7/modules/memcached.so` and the .so.so file is also in that folder.

I runned `memcached -d -u nextcloud` to allow my Nextcloud server to use it, I do not know if it is the correct way, but I think it is.

Of course I added `extension=/usr/lib/php7/modules/memcached.so` in the `/etc/php7/php.ini` file.

I can answer at any question asked by persons who want to help me. In any case I will greatly appreciate any help.

Hej då!

Answer (score 0):

Have you installed the `php7-pecl-memcached` package via `apk`? I tried that and am able to see both the `/usr/lib/php7/modules/memcached.so` file and `memcached` when I run `php -m`.

Comment: Yes I have installed ```php7-pecl-memcached```. This is what I get when I type ```php -m``` : ```PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php7/modules/memcached.so' (tried: /usr/lib/php7/modules/memcached.so (Error relocating /usr/lib/php7/modules/memcached.so: php_session_create_id: symbol not found), /usr/lib/php7/modules//usr/lib/php7/modules/memcached.so.so (Error loading shared library /usr/lib/php7/modules//usr/lib/php7/modules/memcached.so.so: No such file or directory)) in Unknown on line 0
[PHP Modules]
...
memcached
...
```
There is no .so file.

Comment: There is a lot more modules showing but can't put all of them in the comment, only put memcached to show it is there.

Comment: Maybe try uninstalling and reinstalling the `php7-pecl-memcached` package?

Comment: I deleted and added again ```memcached (1.5.20-r0)``` and ```memcached-openrc (1.5.20-r0)``` and ```libmemcached-libs (1.0.18-r4)``` and ```php7-pecl-memcached (3.1.5-r0)```. Doesn't work after that. Is there a command to launch memcached as deamon while I'm using root ? Maybe it's just that it isn't launched properly...

Comment: Are you still receiving the same error after you make those package changes? I need more information than just "didn't work."

Comment: Yes, sorry for the delay, yes I'm still receiving exactly the same errors, which is weird... Maybe the problem comes from ```php7``` itself.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `apk add php7-memcached` instead of `php7-pecl-memcached`?

I just spun up a server on AWS and using that worked well:
https://web.archive.org/web/20200528070633/http://75.101.221.6/

Comment: I just tried, installed the same package that `php7-pecl-memcached`. Same errors that in my original post. Thanks anyway ^^.